# Broad and short lighting: is one more flattering for female portraits? for male?

Tags: portrait, studio-lighting, lighting-basics

[This](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/6495/in-portrait-photography-what-is-broad-lighting-what-is-short-lighting) question explains broad and short lighting.  Could those with portrait experience confirm (or refute) something I've read, which is short lighting tends to be more flattering to females (accentuating form through shadows on neck, shoulders, bust) while broad lighting is more used with male subject.

Is there a rule of thumb that one style is used more with male subjects, and the other with female?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's more about fat/thin than male/female. Short lighting is more flattering for wider people, while broad lighting can be used more freely with thinner faces and forms.